# Cannot Uninstall Purchased Theme, Porto

Tags: theming

I purchased a theme called "Porto" which is quite good.  With that said, for troubleshooting purposes, I need to turn that theme off.

I can uninstall every theme on the site **except** "seven" and this purchased theme.

When we installed the theme, we had to do a whole install using SQL rather than just dragging over the theme file.  I BELIEVE that there is something in these files that is preventing them from being uninstalled but I'm not sure where to look.

Can someone tell me where I might look to find this setting and override it? In the theme file? Setting file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't uninstall the default theme, because there wouldn't be a theme left for the site. Similarly you can't uninstall the Seven theme when it's selected as the admin theme.

You need to change the default to another theme, then under normal circumstances the "Uninstall" link will appear where you'd expect it.

If it doesn't, consult the documentation or contact support for the theme seller, because they've done something non-standard, and it's not likely to be possible to guess what that might have been from afar (especially if it was done as part of the initial SQL import)